# ¿Como personalizar un BottomNavigationView en Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, android-fragment, android-bottom-nav-view

Espero darme a entender con la duda, para de esta manera puedan facilitar el proceso de ayuda, o simplemente de aclaración de las dudas que tengo, estuve investigando un poco sobre el tema, sin embargo no logré encontrar gran cosa, o quizás es que no comprendí completamente.

---

Pues bien, para darme a entender con una mayor claridad, realicé en Adobe XD el prototipo del menú inferior (dicho menú es el del GIF) pero, necesito pasar ese mismo menú a Android Studio, y pensé que la manera mas fácil sería por medio de un BottomNavigationView.

[image: GIF MENÚ INFERIOR]

---

El menú inferior clásico del BottomNavigationView no cuenta con las características que necesito, y de ahí surge mi duda, como lograr que:

1. Como lograr que el texto del icono, supongamos "HOME" se encuentre del lado derecho del icono?
2. Cuando se presione sobre el icono este "icono activo" tenga forma rectangular curva con el fondo "gris" como lo muestro en el GIF.

---

Para implementar el BottomNavigationView utilicé el siguiente código en el Android Studio:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
```

Y este lo coloqué dentro de un Fragment, el cual lo llamé "fragment_inicio", pues el "Activity Main" lo coloqué como un contenedor de Fragments:

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="#FDFDFD"
    design:itemIconTint="#000"
    design:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu"/>
```

Ahora, el código que coloqué en el bottom_navigation_menú fue el siguiente:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item
    android:id="@+id/ic_inicio"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
    android:title="@string/home"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/ic_fav"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_fav"
    android:title="@string/fav"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/ic_filtro"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_label"
    android:title="@string/categ"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/ic_mensaje"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_mensa"
    android:title="@string/chat"/>
```

Espero haberme dado a entender, si fuera necesario colocar alguna parte del código que no coloqué lo haré sin problemas. De antemano saludos, muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola! Creo que el GIF no se muestra, podrías subirlo nuevamente :D

Comment: Si claro ! Disculpa :c

Comment: Creo que ya esta jaja @rguzman

Comment: Ya veo, el layout difiere en el orden con lo nativo, según la guía de material design no existe atributos para modificar la estructura, así que yo optaría por crear un custom bottomNavigationView. Como por ejemplo, una layout con botones y el efecto que deseas se maneja con animaciones.